# How can I make discord bot for strarting minecraft server with python?

Tags: python, discord.py, minecraft

That is my cod now:

```
import discord
import subprocess

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('!StartServer'):
        await message.channel.send('Server is starting')
        subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'D:\Tests\paper\paper-1.18.1-92.jar'])
client.run('token')
```

But when I use command '!StartServer' console whrite this (I already agreed EULA):

```
**Starting org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main
*** Warning, you've not updated in a while! ***
*** Please download a new build as per instructions from https://papermc.io/downloads ***
System Info: Java 17 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.1+12-LTS-39) Host: Windows 10 10.0 (amd64)
Loading libraries, please wait...
2022-01-29 16:44:05,769 ServerMain WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
[16:44:09 INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.**
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you *downloaded a new build as per instructions...*?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych are you about paper's instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple issue :

1. You are running an old paper build. So, such as asked, go [here](https://papermc.io/downloads) then download a newer build.
2. For the eula, the problem is more global. The server is not started at the good place. Let me explain.

You have folder like that:

```
global/
--- server/
    --- paper-1.18.1-92.jar <--- what you want to run
    bot/
    --- bot.py <--- the file you are running
```

You put the exact folder in your python script, so it will use the `paper-1.18.1-92.jar` in the `bot/` folder (in my example).

To fix this, I suggest you to make a script, and run the script from python.

#### Windows

script.bat:

```
@echo off
title MC server
chcp 1252
cd global/server
java -jar paper-1.18.1-92.jar -o true --nogui
```

#### Linux

script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd global/server
java -jar paper-1.18.1-92.jar -o true --nogui
```

The `cd` command make the script in the good folder, and so can be started from everywhere, it will run the good folder.

Comment: I have error now Error: "Unable to access jarfile paper-1.18.1-177.jar"
I else download new build of paper

Comment: @Vladikak And you well write good folder/good file name in script ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Did I need to change anything in "script.bat" or I needed to just copy and paste into my "script.bat"?

Comment: You should change the folder `global/server` into your own, and `paper-1.18.1-92.jar` into your new one

Comment: So I have "Unable to access jarfile paper-1.18.1-177.jar". But I understood how it works. I just moved all my files from server's folder to bot's folder and it works. Thank you very much.